# CM12 Nexus 4 (Mako) GAPPS failing to flash, error: Status 7

Tags: cyanogenmod, 5.0-lollipop, rom-flashing, nexus-4, google-apps

I'm using a rooted, unlocked Nexus 4 with TWRP. I succesfully flashed CM12 but whenever I try to flash GAPPS it fails with error code: Status 7. Which GAPPS.zip should I be using for a Lollipop Nexus 4 CM12?

Comment: The one pointed out on the [corresponding CyanogenMod Wiki page](http://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Google_Apps)?

Comment: No idea then. I've stopped using GApps, and use NOGAPPS instead (see e.g. my answers to [Are there any solutions other than flashing Gapps, to have Google accounts on CyanogenMod?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/62569/16575) and [How to use GPS without using Google Location Services](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/89622/16575)).